# Set a global variable from div data-* attribute in Vuejs3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I am making a vue3 app that get instantiated like this:

```
<div id="my-app" data-string="demo"></div>
<script src=my-app.js></script>
```

I need the value of `data-string` to be set a global variable that is accessible to all of my components, or a way to cleanly get this value and pass it all of my components. I'm using Vue 3 with Typescript. I've tried a few things and can't figure it out. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Well if you are "making the vue app" does this data  really needs to be first initiated inside HTML data attribute. And not other way around as it is intended when designing vue apps?

Comment: Also search "vue share data between components" you can share data from your my-app.js to any component. Or search what "vue store" is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get it done you can do something like this

Get the value **first**

```
const globalScopeValue = document.getElementById('my-app').dataset.string
```

**BEFORE** you create your Vue app!

Then in your App.vue (main Component) use Provide.

Then use Inject in every other component you need this `globalScopeValue`.

Comment: Hi Adam, this first statement returns undefined when I try it. I tried in my main.ts and my App.vue main component file. The provide/inject stuff looks good though! Any ideas on the first part?

Comment: Try to wait until window loads, then take the `data` from `dataset`, and then fire `vue` `app`. Let me know if that helped 